# How to efficiently calculate a conditional product of small size?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, set

This might be more of a math problem than a programming problem, but I've been thinking about this for a while and am having a hard time figuring out if this is a solvable problem.

I have the following:

- Sets **A**, **B** sourced from some set of symbols
- A boolean function **F** : A × B → {0,1}

I wish to construct the set C = {(x,y) : x ∈ A, y ∈ B, with F(x,y) = 1}.

( F can be calculated in O(1) for any pair )

Now up to this point, this calculation would basically consist in just a filter on A × B via the function F, running in O(|A| × |B|), if F is constant time.

**However**, I know one property of C that I feel could help me...

I know that **|C| << |A| |B|**, in fact I'm pretty sure that **|C| is about |A|**. I feel like there's some way to exploit this (I've recently been introduced to probabalistic algorithms, which I feel could help, but I'm definitely not sure).

I imagine some forms of auxiliary structures would be necessary to solve this, which shouldn't be too problematic in themselves, so long as the structures are only polynomial to the size of **A** ( calculating the power sets might be a bit much, A can be a bit big).

This also feels like something that has been proven to have some sort of lower bound complexity, but I don't really have the academic knowledge to prove it.

Any guidance, hints on what domains I should be looking in would be greatly appreciated.

What I have thought about so far:

- This seems a lot like a [SAT issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) but I know next to nothing about those things
- This problem feels slightly isomorphic to the problem of set discrimination (at least... calculating the difference between two sets). I am , however, unable to find any research on the topic in this form (Only getting a lot of "iterate over A, iterate over B" type answers).

Comment: Is your F such that, for fixed x, you can find the y such that F(x,y) = 1 efficiently?

Comment: Yes, but F is far from sparse: I've assumed that , for fixed x , the set { y : F(x,y)=1 } is about the same size as B.

Comment: If your last comment is true, then `|C|` is about the same size as `|A|*|B|`, which contradicts your question. And to answer your question, what you want is not possible without more information about `F`, as you'll need to call `F` on all possible pairs.

Comment: While my last comment holds (at least, I am not allowed to make the opposite assumption), in the specific use case I'm considering, I'm pretty sure that the size approximation is true. There might be some property of F that I'm not considering here I will try to add some context later, but first I need some sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the wording in which you've posed the problem, the only correct solution is a double iteration over A and B and filter, as you've suggested. That's because you've stated the problem as to "construct the set C", which lacking other information, generally means to *enumerate* the set C. The only way to do that and get the exact enumeration of C, at least with the information provided, is to evaluate F on each element in A × B.

In another way of interpreting the problem, you can say you have a definition of C if you have a characteristic function, but that's just F. So I'll assume that's not what you mean.

The key seems to be that you need to elucidate the relevant properties of F, since that's the algorithmic hook for an enumeration of C. What I mean by this is that you should propose an axiom about F that allows you some shortcut over direct filtration. That could mean, for example, the existence of some auxiliary function G that allows a shorter algorithm. Assuming such a G, an enumeration algorithm would evaluate both F and G, rather than F alone.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on trying to make F more explicit. I'll try to find some elucidating property on F